# How can Optic api do where in list?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I have the following XQuery code that uses `op:from-view`.
In the `op:where` section I am trying to select a column that can equal a list of values.
When I use one value like  `op:eq(op:col("client"), $client1)` it works fine.
However i need it to select `($client1, $client2)`.
How do I do that?
I can't seem to find an example anywhere.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optic doesn't have an in() operator at present, so the condition would have to be passed to Optic as

```
op:or((op:eq(op:col("client"), $client1), op:eq(op:col("client"), $client2)))
```

To make that less tedious, one possibility would be to take advantage of build-time expressions as in:

```
op:or(
    let $col := op:col("client")
    for $val in ($client1, $client2)
    return op:eq($col, $val)
    )
```

Or to wrap that expression in a helper function:

```
declare function local:in($colName as xs:string, $vals) {
    op:or(
        let $col := op:col($colName)
        for $val in ($vals)
        return op:eq($col, $val)
        )
};
```

and use it as follows:

```
op:where(
    local:in("client", ($client1, $client2))
    )
```

Hoping that helps,